# Creating an indexed column in R, grouped by user_id, and not increase when NA

Tags: r, indexing

I want to create a column (in R) that indexes the presence of a number in another column grouped by a user_id column. And when the other column is NA, the new desired column should not increase.

The example should bring clarity.
I have this df:

```
data <- data.frame(user_id = c(1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3),
                   one=c(1,NA,3,2,NA,0,NA,4,3,4,NA))

   user_id tobeindexed
1        1           1
2        1          NA
3        1           3
4        2           2
5        2          NA
6        2           0
7        2          NA
8        3           4
9        3           3
10       3           4
11       3          NA
```

I want to make a new column looking like "desired" in the following df:

```
> cbind(data,data.frame(desired = c(1,1,2,1,1,2,2,1,2,3,3)))
   user_id tobeindexed desired
1        1           1       1
2        1          NA       1
3        1           3       2
4        2           2       1
5        2          NA       1
6        2           0       2
7        2          NA       2
8        3           4       1
9        3           3       2
10       3           4       3
11       3          NA       3
```

How can I solve this?

Using colsum and group_by gets me close, but the count does not start over from 1 when the user_id changes...

```
> data %>% group_by(user_id) %>% mutate(desired = cumsum(!is.na(tobeindexed)))

   user_id tobeindexed   desired
     <dbl>       <dbl> <int>
 1       1           1     1
 2       1          NA     1
 3       1           3     2
 4       2           2     3
 5       2          NA     3
 6       2           0     4
 7       2          NA     4
 8       3           4     5
 9       3           3     6
10       3           4     7
11       3          NA     7
```

Comment: Not sure why your dplyr version is not working, my guess is it might have something to do with your sample data defined with `$one` and all your other output and code being defined with `$tobeindexed`. Perhaps you still have `tobeindexed` (a non-frame object) in your environment?

Answer (score 0):

Given the sample data you provided (with the `one`) column, this works unchanged. The code is retained below for demonstration.

## base R

```r
data$out <- ave(data$one, data$user_id, FUN = function(z) cumsum(!is.na(z)))
data
#    user_id one out
# 1        1   1   1
# 2        1  NA   1
# 3        1   3   2
# 4        2   2   1
# 5        2  NA   1
# 6        2   0   2
# 7        2  NA   2
# 8        3   4   1
# 9        3   3   2
# 10       3   4   3
# 11       3  NA   3
```

## dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
data %>%
  group_by(user_id) %>%
  mutate(out = cumsum(!is.na(one))) %>%
  ungroup()
# # A tibble: 11 × 3
#    user_id   one   out
#      <dbl> <dbl> <int>
#  1       1     1     1
#  2       1    NA     1
#  3       1     3     2
#  4       2     2     1
#  5       2    NA     1
#  6       2     0     2
#  7       2    NA     2
#  8       3     4     1
#  9       3     3     2
# 10       3     4     3
# 11       3    NA     3
```